# PHP Redirection Error (even tho I'm pretty sure I wrote this right...)

Tags: php, mysql

login.php

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
        $user=$_POST['user'];
        $pass=$_POST['pass'];

        $con=mysql_connect('localhost','Haha I almost forgot to take this stuff out.','Whoops. That wouldve been bad.') or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db('Jesus. I almost forgot this one too!') or die("cannot select DB");

        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='".$user."' AND password='".$pass."'");
        $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($numrows!=0)
        {
           while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
           {
              $dbusername=$row['username'];
              $dbpassword=$row['password'];
           }

           if($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword)
           {
              session_start();
              $_SESSION['sess_user']=$user;

              /* Redirect browser */
              header("Location: member.php");
           }
        } else {
           echo "Invalid username or password!";
        }

    } else {
       echo "All fields are required!";
    }
}
```

I've successfully created an account (I can see it in my database), however when I log in it just redirects me to the login page again.

If I manually direct myself to the member.php page it works fine (I can see that I'm logged in and the session is started), however if I just try to login it never redirects me.

I'm sure it's something simple and I'm just missing it, but could you help me?

(inb4 u yell at me for using mysql instead of mysqli I'm just testing K? I'll fix it eventually D:)

Comment: Also try adding an `exit;` after the `header()` statement or code will just continue executing within this script. A `header()` statement does not terminate execution, it just sends a header to the browser!

Comment: doesn't make sense having to fetch, then comparing the input, you already have the match if the row exists ( > 0), its enough

Comment: Hmm... The code looks ok. Start from first principles. Check that the 'header' statement is actually executing by putting an echo statement of something before it. It will probably trip a 'Header already sent' error but you will know it gets there. Which is my second point - did you add the _error_reporting_ to the top of the script?

Comment: If i assume that the redirect is working - are there any checks in _'member.php'_ that will redirect you back to this script? i.e does 'member.php' check _$_SESSION['sess_user']_ check that the index is 'sess_user'.

Comment: make sure your cookies are enabled. make sure your not unsetting anything in other scripts. what does your member.php code look like? I would  add an exit(); underneath header(..) Most likely your session is never written.

Answer (score 0):

May I'm reading this wrong, but it looks like you have an extra bracket in there

```
header("Location: member.php");
    }
    }
```

Comment: He just cannot be bothered to indent his code inteligently to make it readable to the people he wants help from

Comment: It's indented properly..
The second bracket is for 
`if($numrows!=0)`

Comment: I see the issue. Sorry.
When I pasted the code I used ctrl+k to format it all, and it automatically indented it.

Comment: this should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Find ...

```
if($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword)
{
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['sess_user']=$user;
  /* Redirect browser */
  header("Location: member.php");
}
```

change to ...

```
if($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword)
{
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['sess_user']= $dbusername;
  session_write_close();
  /* Redirect browser */
  header('Location: member.php');
  die();
}
```

Also you might want to make use of mysql_free_result() and mysql_close().

Comment: Tried adding `die();` to the end. Same result.

Any ideas?